# QPixmap / QPainter showing black window background

Tags: python, pyqt5, qpainter, qpixmap

I am following an example from the PyQt5 book by Martin Fitzpatrick. When I run the following code, the background is black and the line is not drawn:

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets, uic
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt

class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        
        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel()

        canvas = QtGui.QPixmap(400, 300)

        self.label.setPixmap(canvas)
        self.setCentralWidget(self.label)
        self.draw_something()

    def draw_something(self):
        painter = QtGui.QPainter(self.label.pixmap())
        painter.drawLine(10, 10, 300, 200)
        painter.end()


app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
window = MainWindow()
window.show()
app.exec_()
```

The expected result is on the left:
[image: Comparison]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

By default the memory that a QPixmap uses is not cleaned by efficiency so it has the bytes not altered as indicated by [the docs](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qpixmap.html#QPixmap):

> #### QPixmap::QPixmap(int width, int height)
>
> Constructs a pixmap with the
> given width and height. If either width or height is zero, a null
> pixmap is constructed.
>
> **Warning:** **This will create a QPixmap with uninitialized data.** Call
> fill() to fill the pixmap with an appropriate color before drawing
> onto it with QPainter.

<sub>(emphasis mine)</sub>

The solution is to use fill to set the background color:

```
canvas = QtGui.QPixmap(400, 300)
canvas.fill(QtGui.QColor("white"))
```